# Dependencies to install wine

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to install wine but it is asking for this dependency

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building a dependency tree
Reading status information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This could mean that
you requested an impossible situation or, if you are using the
unstable distribution, that some required packages were not
created yet or removed from "Incoming".
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~kinetic-1)
```